# Create menu from JSON

Tags: c#, json, wpf, menu

I need to create menu items which get from json file. I already deserialized the json file but I don't know how to add the items to the menu control.`

What I got so far:

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("D:\\WORKING\\BOUNCEFORMS\\Week8\\Feb18\\New folder\\dynamicmenu\\dynamicmenu\\menulist.json"))
{
    json = r.ReadToEnd();
    JObject objJobject = JObject.Parse(json);
    string somestr = objJobject["Menu1"].ToString();

    string somestr2 = somestr.Remove(0, 1);
    string somestr3 = somestr2.Remove(somestr2.Length - 1);            

    JObject subobject = JObject.Parse(somestr3);
    string somesubstr = subobject["SubMenu1"].ToString();

    string a = somesubstr.Remove(0, 1);
    string b = a.Remove(a.Length - 1);

    JObject strjobj = JObject.Parse(b);
    string strsub = strjobj["Text"].ToString();             

    List<string> menus = new List<string>();
    menus.itemsource=strsub;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a loop to create all MenuItems.

**While working in Code behind:**

```
<Menu x:Name="MyMenu"></Menu> //Define a Menu in your XAML
```

In your MyWindow.xaml.cs you can add the Items.

```
MyMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem()
        {
            Header = "", //Your Header for this Item (Part of your JSON i guess..)              
        });
```

**While working with Bindings:**

Bind your Menu like this:

```
 <Menu ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MenuItems, 
                             Mode=OneWay, 
                             UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Add a Property to your ViewModel (`ObservableCollection<string>` or better `ObservableCollection<MenuItem>`).

Simply add your Items you get from JSON to that collection.

Don't forget to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`